# Variable scope witihin requirejs modules

Tags: requirejs

I am new to requirejs and don't understand variable scope.

So previously, for example, I had:

```
var Foo = "some value";

function firstFunction () {

    //do something with Foo here
    console.log(Foo); 

    }


 function secondFunction () {

    //do something else with Foo here
    console.log(Foo); 

    }
```

But within a module

```
define(function() {

   return {

      //how do I declare Foo within the module so it is available to firstFunction and secondFunction?

      firstFunction: function() {
          //do something with Foo here
          console.log(Foo);
          },

      secondFunction: secondFunction () {
         //do something else with Foo here
         console.log(Foo);
         }
     }

    });
```

Is there a way of declaring the variable Foo within the module and to make it available to  firstFunction() and secondFunction()?

Comment: You can add your `var Foo` on the line before `return`.

Comment: RequireJS is not a factor at all in your problem here. If you understand how scopes work in JavaScript than you understand how to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes. That works. Thanks.